# Incorrect syntax near ',' (dbnull issue)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

It suppose there is chart to be appeared. But, it doesnt  as there is problem regarding dbnull issue. This happen when either one of three select statement has no data.

```
Dim user As String = Session("NoMatrik")
        Dim resultId As Object = Session("max")

        Dim idQuery = "select max(resultid) as id from tblResult where result_nomatric = @matric and result_quiz_id = 1 UNION All " +
                      "select max(resultid) as id from tblResult where result_nomatric = @matric and result_quiz_id = 2 UNION All " +
                      "select max(resultid) as id from tblResult where result_nomatric = @matric and result_quiz_id = 3"
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmdGetId As New SqlCommand(idQuery, conn)
        cmdGetId.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matric", user)

        Dim maxIDs As SqlDataReader = cmdGetId.ExecuteReader
        Dim IDs As String = ""
        While maxIDs.Read
            IDs += maxIDs("id").ToString() + ", "
        End While
        maxIDs.Close()
        IDs = IDs.Substring(0, IDs.Length - 2)

        Dim cmdString = "Select tblResult.result_quiz_id as Quiz,count(TblAnswer.AnswerType) as  answerCount , TblAnswer.AnswerType " +
                        "from TblResultDetail inner join TblAnswer on TblResultDetail.ResultDetail_Answer_Id = TblAnswer.AnswerId " +
                        "inner join tblResult on tblResult.resultid = TblResultDetail.ResultDetail_Result_Id " +
                        "where TblResultDetail.ResultDetail_Result_Id in (" + IDs + ") " +
                        "group by TblAnswer.AnswerType, tblResult.result_quiz_id order by TblAnswer.AnswerType"


        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdString, conn)

        If IsDBNull(resultId) Then
            Label1.Visible = True
            chrtResult.Visible = False
        Else

            Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader
            dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader

            While dr1.Read()
                Dim tempArr(0) As Double
                Dim count As Double = dr1("answerCount")
                tempArr(0) = count
                Dim Type As String = dr1("AnswerType").ToString()
                Dim level As Integer = dr1("Quiz")
                chrtResult.Series(Type).Points(level - 1).YValues = tempArr
            End While
        End If
        conn.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

an error, Incorrect syntax near '(' appear at line  `dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader`. So , how I want to fix this error?

Comment: Are your id's string or numeric values?

Comment: varchar. i have condition where there is no data at all , then message(label1) will be shown. but , if the data is not complete, Incorrect syntax near '(' appear at line  dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your first query to exclude any `Null` values using a `HAVING` clause like so:

```
Dim idQuery = "select max(resultid) as id from tblResult " + 
              "where result_nomatric = @matric and result_quiz_id = 1 " +
              "having max(resultid) is not null " +
              "UNION All " +
              "select max(resultid) as id from tblResult " + 
              "where result_nomatric = @matric and result_quiz_id = 2 " + 
              "having max(resultid) is not null " +
              "UNION All " +
              "select max(resultid) as id from tblResult " + 
              "where result_nomatric = @matric and result_quiz_id = 3 " +
              "having max(resultid) is not null"
```

The `having max(resultid) is not null` will exclude any nulls in your `UNION ALL`.

If there are no `IDs` returned, you simply need to do a check on this before you execute your next block of code and do as @DmitriE suggests with the adding of quotes. Reorganise it to look like:

```
While maxIDs.Read
    IDs += "'" + maxIDs("id").ToString() + "', "
End While    

If IDs = "" Then
    Label1.Visible = True
    chrtResult.Visible = False
Else
    IDs = IDs.Substring(0, IDs.Length - 2)
    Dim cmdString = "Select ....."

    Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader
    dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader

    While dr1.Read()
        ' YOUR WHILE LOOP CODE HERE'
    End While
End If
```

Comment: there is error at line  IDs = IDs.Substring(0, IDs.Length - 2)
'length cannot be less than zero'

Comment: I updated the post after my last comment to move the `substring` part into the `else` clause, did you test the latest version? so it will only evaluate that substring if you have a string to perform the operation on

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
While maxIDs.Read
    IDs += "'" + maxIDs("id").ToString() + "', "
End While
```

and then you need to remove last single quote.

in clause should follow this format: where x.id in ('id1', 'id2', 'idN')

Comment: if there is no dbnull,  there is no problem. error occur when one of the select statement at idquery is not fulfilled.

Comment: I would then want to check maxIDs before proceeding and handle it if it is null...